# FACEBOOK error missing class if class included

Tags: php, facebook

where I did mistake? I did copy code from facebook develop center but I don't know where is the mistake .... Please help me ;) It's shame that it is not classic php ... :/

Code:

```
<?php
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php')  ;
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;


FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('531817970165190', 'd589d0ae5b2a46ca1240670da41204ed');

// If you already have a valid access token:
 $sessi FacebookSession('access-token');

// If you're making app-level requests:
 $sessi

// To validate the session:
try {
  $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
  // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
  echo $ex->getMessage();}  


if($session) {
  try {

    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
 $resp>execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    echo "Ahoj " . $request->getName();

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }  

}

?>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' not found in /home/users/acerr/docasne.cekuj.net/web/fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 33
```

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question posting.

Comment: Obviously you're missing that class

Answer (score 1):

You have to include FacebookSDKException before FacebookRequestException. The error is that FacebookRequestException can't find FacebookSDKException.

Do you have a link to the page where you copied the code I would be happy to tell the documentation people to update it.

Comment: Ok, but how can i fix it? I have included SDKEXCEPTION AND REQUESTEXCEPTION ....

Comment: Change the order you require the files.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `FacebookRequestException` needs `FacebookSDKException` in order to load.  Loading bit somewhere near the top isn't enough; `FacebookSDKException` needs to be loaded *before* `FacebookRequestException`.

Unlike, say, Java's `import` statement, PHP's `require_once` is an actual command that executes on the line where you put it.  When the error you're getting occurs, this is all that has run:

```
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php')  ;
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
// Lines after this point haven't run yet, and so don't count
```

To fix this problem, import `FacebookSDKException` before `FacebookRequestException`:

```
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php')  ;
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once ('fb/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
```

Comment: Pretty hopeless that this is not handled within the api classes themselves if you ask me.

Comment: @ArnovanOordt True - most libraries handle their own includes; it's strange that these don't.